# How do you create a file/folder explorer tree with Desktop as the root?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**Introduction**

When you view the Windows explorer tree, it shows the Desktop as the root directory. Its children include all the files/folders in it **PLUS** Libraries, Homegroup, the User's folder, Computer, Network, Control Panel and Recycle Bin.

**Problem**

I already created an explorer tree for my program but the root directories are the main drives, which I obtained using `Directory.GetLogicalDrives()`.

I want to be able to make Desktop as the root. I tried using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

and

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

but both only return the files/folders in it. Libraries, Homegroup, the User's folder, Computer, Network, Control Panel and Recycle Bin are all missing.

**Question**

How do I create this kind of explorer tree? Do I need to manually add those missing folders as children of the Desktop directory? (I am using WPF)

Comment: All of that are special folders or not folders at all. Explorer has it as hardcoded value and adds them manually, they aren't stored in 'Desktop' folder. [How to work with libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-7-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference)